# Returning last created csv file from subdirectories

Tags: python, glob, os.walk, os.path

This is the structure of my directory. I want to go into the subdirectories that start with "F3E3" and then return the csv's that contain "0.1Hz" in the filename. There are two csv's in each subdirectory that contain "0.1Hz" in the filename. I only want to return the last created file.

```
 DATA
      F3E319
        F3E319_TEST.csv
        F3E319_TEST_0.1Hz_11_21.csv
        F3E319_TEST_0.1Hz_11_20.csv
        F3E319_TEST_0.1Hz.png
      F3E320
        F3E320_TEST.csv
        F3E320_TESTTEST_0.1Hz_11_21.csv
        F3E320_TESTTEST_0.1Hz_11_20.csv
        F3E320_TEST_0.1Hz.png
      F3E321
        F3E320_TEST.csv
        F3E320_TEST2_0.1Hz_11_21.csv
        F3E320_TEST2_0.1Hz_11_20.csv
        F3E320_TEST_0.1Hz.png
      F3ES1
        F3ES1_TEST.csv
        F3ES1_TEST15_0.1Hz.csv
```

Desired Output:

```
DATA\F3E319\F3E319_TEST_0.1Hz_11_21.csv
DATA\F3E320\F3E320_TESTTEST_0.1Hz_11_21.csv
DATA\F3E321\F3E320_TEST2_0.1Hz_11_21.csv
```

I have been using this code to find all the csv's with "0.1Hz":

```
import os.path
keyword = "0.1Hz"
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(r"\DATA"):
    for filename in [f for f in filenames if f.endswith(".csv")]:
       if keyword in filename:
          print(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))
```

**I cannot figure out how to only go into the sub-directories that start with "F3E3" and how to only return the last created csv with "0.1Hz".**

I know that you can do something like this, but I'm not sure how to incorporate it into my current code:

```
for file in glob.glob('\DATA\F3E3*):
  print file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `os.listdir` to iterate through the subdirectories and csv files so that is easier to find the last created file in the subdirectories. Since getting file creation time may varies depending on the operating system you're using (see [How to get file creation & modification date/times in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237079/how-to-get-file-creation-modification-date-times-in-python)), I add the `creation_date` function and use it to sort the list of csv files.

```
import os
import platform

def creation_date(path_to_file):
    if platform.system() == 'Windows':
        return os.path.getctime(path_to_file)
    else:
        stat = os.stat(path_to_file)
        try:
            return stat.st_birthtime
        except AttributeError:
            return stat.st_mtime

directory = "DATA"
subdirs = [os.path.join(directory, fl) for fl in os.listdir(directory) if fl.startswith("F3E3")]
for subdir in subdirs:
    filenames = [os.path.join(subdir, fl) for fl in os.listdir(subdir) if fl.endswith(".csv") and ("0.1Hz" in fl)]
    filenames=sorted(filenames, key=creation_date, reverse=True)
    print(filenames[0])
```